# php & mysql: most efficient method to check large array against database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, multidimensional-array, comparison

I have a large set of data stored in a multi-dimensional array. An example structure is as below:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => motomummy.com
            [1] => 1921
            [2] => 473
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => kneedraggers.com
            [1] => 3051
            [2] => 5067
        )
)
```

I also have a table in a mysql database that `currently` contains ~80K domain names. This list will grow monthly by possibly ~10K+ domain names. The goal is to compare Array[][0] (the domain name) against the mysql database and return an array with preserved values (but key preservation is **not** important) that only contains unique values.

Please note, that I only want to compare the first index alone, **NOT** the entire array.

The initial multi-dimensional array is assumed to be enormous in size (more than likely anywhere from 100k to 10 million results). What is the best way to get data back that is not contained in the database?

What I am doing now is simply storing to an array, the complete list of domains from the database, then using the following function, comparing each value in the initial array against the database array. This is horribly slow and inefficient obviously.

```
// get result of custom comparison function
$clean = array_filter($INITIAL_LIST, function($elem) {
$wordOkay = true;

// check every word in "filter from database" list, store it only if not in list           
    foreach ($this->domains as $domain) {
        if (stripos($elem[0], $domain) !== false) {
            $wordOkay = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $wordOkay;
});
```

Some pseudo code or even actual code would be very helpful at this point.

Comment: So you want the entries of `"array"` that are not present in the database?

Comment: Precisely, maybe I'll reword my question a bit to clarify.

Comment: Why not just use a `SELECT` statement

Comment: That was my next thought, but for performance sake, is that most efficient and fastest? Running a SELECT for 80,000 results doesn't seem that efficient, but I really don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DBMS! It  was made for stuff like that.

- Create a temporary table temp { id (fill with array index); url (filled with url)}
- Fill it with your array's data
- Ideally create an index on `temp.url`
- Query the database:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM `temp` LEFT JOIN `urls`
  WHERE urls.url = temp.url AND urls.url IS NULL;
  ```

  (the table `urls` is your existing data)